# How to use Qt library on iPhone

Tags: iphone, qt, ipad

I am develop a stock view app on iPad. I figure out that qtstalker app can run on Mac, with Qt library. Now I can run qtstalker on Mac, compile with XCode after qmake all the subdirectory of qtstalker.

Now I would like to port this program to iPad. I know that I can not port completely without modification. How I can configure qmake, project file to port it to iPad?

I will be appreciated with your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is only one active Qt iPhone porting http://qt.gitorious.org/+qt-iphone/qt/qt-iphone-clone. The latest code submitted 10 days ago. So it looks that the guy is still working on that.

See also another project from Qt: [Introducing New Port of Qt to](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/10/02/introducing-new-port-of-qt-to-your-favourite-platform/)